# google map not rendering in 4.1 .2 device with google map version2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am trying to get hands on with android google map V2 with the sample code given by google .

I am able to build the code without any error in eclipse . (I have followed the steps given in the tutorial) . When i am trying to run that in samsung tablet 4.1.2 google map is not being rendered with error "**Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.**"

But when i run the same code on samsung tablet having android version 2.3 it works fine and google map is being rendered .

Comment: Sounds like your api key is incorrect, although then it shouldn't work on Android 2.3 neither. Maybe check if the api key is saved in some folder like values-v8

Comment: where can i find this folder

Comment: It is an example. It probably does not exists. Point is, check if you are actually using a key, and the correct one, on the Android versions that do not work. Read how the /res/ folder works with supporting multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late reply but just wanted to put it here as I was stuck with the same problem and my error log saying

```
     04-17 21:07:50.422: E/Google Maps Android API(4471): Authorization failure.  Please see 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
    04-17 21:07:50.422: E/Google Maps Android API(4471): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.mapdemo, API Key: AIzaSyCvGBr5in13NK2yYBR7lhXTtnxj3mrXQy4, Certificate Fingerprint: 0347A985F68AE96A56ABE71E95A6F632CB13A212
```

Refer to the key generation process for the app here and it can be resolved by putting the correct key in the manifest.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key